# how can I show the date in a columns header every day with total?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to make the statistic page in MVC how to make the controller and view to be like this output and show the date in the column with every day for example :

```
department     day1||(SAMPLES_MORNING) ,  day1 || (SAMPLES_EVENING) , day2 || (SAMPLES_MORNING) , day2 || (SAMPLES_EVENING) , .......
```

[image]

this is the model class :

```
    public partial class STATISTICS_DAILY
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DEPT_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SAMPLES_MORNING { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SAMPLES_EVENING { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> hospital_no { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> user_id { get; set; }
    
        public virtual stat_Departments stat_Departments { get; set; }
        public virtual sys_users sys_users { get; set; }
        public virtual Hospital Hospital { get; set; }
        public virtual sys_users sys_users1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

in the statistic 1M means first date morning total number of samples and 1E means first date evening total number of samples
2M means second date morning total number of samples and 2E means second date evening total number of samples and so on till last day

I tried this is the controller :

```
 public ActionResult SamplesSttat()
        {
            
            int HospitalId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["HospitalID"]);
            var sTATISTICS_DAILY = db.STATISTICS_DAILY.Include(s => s.stat_Departments)
                .Include(s => s.Hospital).Where(x => x.hospital_no == HospitalId)
                .Include(s => s.sys_users1);
            return View(sTATISTICS_DAILY.OrderByDescending(stat => stat.DATE).ToList());
        }
```

and this is the view :

```
@model IEnumerable<warehouse.Models.STATISTICS_DAILY>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SamplesSttat";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Statistic</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stat_Departments.Dept_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SAMPLES_MORNING)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SAMPLES_EVENING)
        </th>
       
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DATE)
        </th>
       
       
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stat_Departments.Dept_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SAMPLES_MORNING)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SAMPLES_EVENING)
        </td>
    
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DATE)
        </td>
       
       
       
       
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

This is the current output view :

[image]

How can I put the date column up and view each day in a column not in the rows like the statistic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in different way

I did a crystal report cross-tab report this kind of report will do such statistics

Also I will try to do it in MVC controller and view if I find the way I will post it

Thanks